# how to set the checked/unchecked of CheckedTextView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have create android listview that fill in using String array. I want to give checked/unchecked functionality it  using android CheckedTextView widget. so how could I do this.? I googled using lot of key worlds but unable to find suitable tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found you a nice post that will help you out

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3e6c3c11353f59dc?pli=1

basicly, you call isItemChecked() on your listview to determine if it's checked or not, and what item is.

Answer (score 0):

create xml file and put CheckedTextView in it and then create your own custom `ListView` By extending the `ListView` and inflate the same layout..

if you have apiDemos then you will find a class called `List14.java` which can guide you how to design such a ListView